# Function like `enumerate` for arrays with custom indices?

Tags: indexing, iteration, julia

For an array with a [non-one based index](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/offset-arrays/index.html) like:

```
using OffsetArrays
a = OffsetArray( [1,2,3], -1)
```

Is there a simple way to get a tuple of `(index,value)`, similar to `enumerate`?

Enumerating still counts the elements... `collect(enumerate(a))` returns:

```
3-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 1)
 (2, 2)
 (3, 3)
```

I'm looking for:

```
 (0, 1)
 (1, 2)
 (2, 3)
```

Comment: Try `pairs` in place of `enumerate`.

Comment: @DNF please make that an answer, it's much more canonical than tupling with `eachindex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical solution is to use `pairs`:

```
julia> a = OffsetArray( [1,2,3], -1);

julia> for (i, x) in pairs(a)
       println("a[", i, "]: ", x)
       end
a[0]: 1
a[1]: 2
a[2]: 3

julia> b = [1,2,3];

julia> for (i, x) in pairs(b)
       println("b[", i, "]: ", x)
       end
b[1]: 1
b[2]: 2
b[3]: 3
```

It works for other types of collections too:

```
julia> d = Dict(:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3);

julia> for (i, x) in pairs(d)
       println("d[:", i, "]: ", x)
       end
d[:a]: 1
d[:b]: 2
d[:c]: 3
```

You can find a lot of other interesting iterators by reading the documentation of `Base.Iterators`.

Answer (score 3):

Try `eachindex(a)` to get the indexes, see the example below:

```
julia> tuple.(eachindex(a),a)
3-element OffsetArray(::Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}, 0:2) with eltype Tuple{Int64,Int64} with indices 0:2:
 (0, 1)
 (1, 2)
 (2, 3)
```

Comment: This has the distinct disadvantage of allocating an unnecessary array, twice as big as the original, which is normally not wanted for this type of iteration. You can improve it by using `zip(eachindex(a), a)`.

Comment: This is very nice! `zip` - will create a non-materialized iterator. However, he probably needs to iterate over that objects or do anything else with them and in the end those values will be materialized anyway. For example try ` @time for (a,b) in zip(eachindex(a),a); a+b; end` vs  `@time for (a,b) in tuple.(eachindex(a),a); a+b; end` - both will have almost identical memory allocations.

Comment: and `pairs` looks better anyway :-)

Comment: Actually, `tuple.(eachindex(a), a)` will allocate twice the amount of memory of `a`, while `zip(eachindex(a), a)` give *zero* allocations. For a simple test I did, the `tuple.` version was three times as slow. The values of the iterators are indeed returned, but it doesn't cause any allocations, since they are just scalar values, not heap allocated arrays.